Clique Covering - Does it help knowing a graph can be partitioned into equal-sized cliques with known representatives?
I have a class of graphs which have the following property:
Let $G$ be a graph from this class. I know for this graph exists, for a known $n\in ℕ$, a partition of its vertices $V(G)$ into $n$ groups $V_1,...,V_n\subseteq V(G)$, all of which are the same size, such that each of these groups is a clique.
I furthermore know that each of these cliques is a clique of maximum size for $G$. Finally I know for each clique one of its members, i.e. we know vertices $v_1,...,v_n\in V(G)$ with $\forall i\in[n]:\quad v_i\in V_i$.
I guess this problem is NP-complete, since similar variants (but without known representatives for the cliques) like clique covering or finding the partition of a graph such that as many edges lie within one of these partition groups are as well.
But especially that we know representatives puts me at a loss as to how one would prove this.

If you have a clique cover where all the cliques are maximum cliques, then the given clique cover is optimal.
Any clique cover requires at least $\left\lceil\frac{\vert V(G)\vert} {\omega(G)}\right\rceil$ cliques. Here $\omega(G)$ denotes the size of the maximum clique in $G$. The clique cover you have achieves this bound tightly.

I totally forgot asking the question I actually wanted to ask, i.e. if we can deduce the vertices of each group in polynomial time. Should I edit or ask as new question?

@ConnFus Do you mean in case you don't actually know the vertices of the optimal clique cover? But it's still not $NP$-complete, because the promise already contains the answer (even though not a certificate) to both the maximum clique and the clique cover problems.

Yes, I only know one representative of each group, and would like to find the remaining group members. True, now that I think about it, the decision variant sounds trivial. So I'd probably have to formulate it as search problem, so the corresponding complexity class would be #P?

@ConnFus The corresponding class would be some functional class. Trivially, the problem of finding the certificate belongs to $FNP$, which is assumed to be far weaker than $#P$. The promise, of course, also puts the problem inside the $coFNP$ class, which means it's unlikely $FNP$-hard.
